# Opening .docx/.docm file inline to <iframe> in IE-8 browser with JSF 2.0 is showing blank iframe with multiple session

Tags: iframe, jsf-2, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008, office-2010

I am using <iframe> to open MS Office 2007/2010 document file like docx/docm in a JSF 2.0 project that is deployed at Websphere App Server 8.5, and accessing its url from a client having Windows Server 2008 and MS Office 2010 installed with IE-8 browser. the src of <iframe> is the document url, the example code of <iframe> is exampled here from my .xhtml page.

```
<iframe width = "80%" height = "90%" src = "http://<ip>/files/test.docx">
```

When we open the respective url with this <iframe>, test.docx document is viewed inline in iframe (MS Office 2007/2010 don't open their documents in IE, they are forced to open by using registry values against them)...any how they are opening after the registry editing...and this is what we desired. but the issue is quite complex and unable to understood.

When we open multiple session of the same .xhtml page having some iframe with some different document url/similar it will behave randomly with following problems...

- it shows document in iframe with some new sessions, and u don't close the session and create some new as well, it will show the word document in newly opening ie-window with iframe, but when we switched back to other previous sessions, it has been noticed that word application that was launched inline in iframe previously is not visible any more, for launching it again it need to be refreshed...
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555450/opening-docx-docm-file-inline-to-iframe-in-ie-8-browser-with-jsf-2-0-is-givi
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555619/opening-docx-docm-file-inline-to-iframe-in-ie-8-browser-with-jsf-2-0-is-open

it would be good to have some inputs or any solution...

Comment: Your question is too broad and covers too many issues. Office 2010 does not open documents inline in IE any longer (the COM DocObjects were deprecated many years ago).

Comment: Ok @EricLaw i should re-write the issues separately. yes Office 2010 doesn't open its documents inline in IE-8 or later but we can force it to do so by entering some registry values.

Comment: plz see the link from microsoft to open up office document inline in IE http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982995